# How to open a partial Modal Form in VSTO?

Tags: c#, vsto

I want to open a form in VSTO by which I should be still able to select the Excel cells but should not be able to access any Menus or create a new sheet.

I have the below code for now, but which this, I am still able to click menu buttons. I don't want to disable each and every menu button from code

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Show(new WindowFormsWrapper(new IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Windows[1].Hwnd)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Word has a [protection feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-protection-in-your-document-workbook-or-presentation-05084cc3-300d-4c1a-8416-38d3e37d6826) that only lets you make certain modifications, like to document content, or styles. Excel seems to have it too but my proxy isn't letting me open that page so I can't tell what it does and doesn't allow. If that's not close enough, you're probably out of luck because Office is not really designed to be used in this way.

Also, FYI you shouldn't access the VSTO API from your non-modal dialog. [Multi-threading in VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2017) is generally fraught with peril.

You might consider using a task pane instead. There would be no threading issues here, assuming you don't create your own threads inside it.

Comment: Thanks Chris! But  i am looking to have a RefEdit control which is not available in VSTO, so i would need something which can allow for me to select only cells to get range and not allow to click on any menu when the form is open

Comment: I don't know much about RefEdit, but I would not be surprised if there was not a good way to re-create RefEdit. Office is focused primarily on the average user, rather than developers. Hopefully you can get what you're looking for though.